# Terminating or aborting an HTTP request

Tags: http, go, error-handling, exit, abort

What's the way to abort my **API** serving with some error message?

Link to call my service:

```
http://creative.test.spoti.io/api/getVastPlayer?add=
    {"Json":Json}&host=api0.spoti.io&domain=domain&userAgent=userAgent&mobile=true
```

To call my service the client need to send a Json and some params.

I want to test if the params that I get are correct, if not I want send a error message.

The response should be a Json Code `{"Result":"Result","Error":"error message"}`

I tried `log.fatal` and `os.Exit(1)` they stop the service, not just the call request. `panic` aborts the call but it prevents me to send a `http.ResponseWriter` which is my error message.

I read something about **panic, defer, recover** but I don't really know how can I use them to solve this problem.

`return` works:

```
mobile :=query.Get("mobile")
if mobile=="mobile" {
            str:=`{"Resultt":"","Error":"No valide Var"}`
            fmt.Fprint(w, str)      
            fmt.Println("No successfull Operation!!")
            return}
```

**But I can use it just in the main function, because in the other functions it exits just the func not the caller function (request).**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terminating the serving of an HTTP request is nothing more than to return from the `ServeHTTP()` method, e.g.:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // examine incoming params
    if !ok {
        str := `{"Result":"","Error":"No valide Var"}`
        fmt.Fprint(w, str)
        return
    }

    // Do normal API serving
})

panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

**Notes:**

If the input params of your API service are invalid, you should consider returning an HTTP error code instead of the implied default `200 OK`. For this you can use the [`http.Error()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error) function, for example:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // examine incoming params
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, `Invalid input params!`, http.StatusBadRequest) 
        return
    }

    // Do normal API serving
})
```

For a more sophisticated example where you send back JSON data along with the error code:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // examine incoming params
    if !ok {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        str := `{"Result":"","Error":"No valide Var"}`
        fmt.Fprint(w, str)
        return
    }

    // Do normal API serving
})
```

**Example showing how to propagate "returning"**

If the error is detected outside of `ServeHTTP()`, e.g. in a function that is called from `ServeHTTP()`, you have to return this error state so that `ServeHTTP()` can return.

Let's assume you have the following custom type for your required parameters and a function which is responsible to decode them from a request:

```
type params struct {
    // fields for your params 
}

func decodeParams(r *http.Request) (*params, error) {
    p := new(params)
    // decode params, if they are invalid, return an error:

    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("Invalid params")
    }

    // If everything goes well:
    return p, nil
}
```

Using these:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    p, err := decodeParams(r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, `Invalid input params!`, http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // Do normal API serving
})
```

Also see this related question: [Golang, how to return in func FROM another func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858823/golang-how-to-return-in-func-from-another-func)

Comment: yes, I said for the the main function it's OK ,but for  the other functions it doesn't work because **return** exit just the function not the  HTTP request.

Comment: @Aziz Then you have to return this error state to `ServeHTTP()` so that it can return. See the edited answer which shows an example to this.