# How do I assign specific http status codes?

Tags: go

I wrote this small api and I am using a validator to validate request fields and I am propagating errors up in the response but not error codes, I would like to be able to add a custom error message and assign specific status codes. For example: If improper types are passed I would like to message that improper types have been passed and the status code would be 400, Missing fields required would be 422, Internal Server Error would be 500. I am struggling implementing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
type Trade struct {
    ClientTradeId string `json:"client_trade_id" validate:"nonzero"`
    Date          int    `json:"date" validate:"nonzero, min=20010101, max=21000101"`
    Quantity      string `json:"quantity" validate:"nonzero, regexp=^[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$"`
    Price         string `json:"price" validate:"nonnil, nonzero, regexp=^[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$"`
    Ticker        string `json:"ticker" validate:"nonzero, nonnil"`
}
type InternalTrade struct {
    Id string `json:"Id" validate:"nonzero"`
    Trade *Trade `json:"Trade"`
}

type TradeSubmitted struct {

    TradeId string `json:"TradeId" validate:"nonzero"`
    ClientTradeId string `json:"clientTradeId" validate:"nonzero"`

}

type Error struct {
    Message string `json:"Message"`
}


var trades []InternalTrade
var (
    tradeValidator = validator.NewValidator()
)
func createTrade(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    var trade Trade
    var tradeSubmitted TradeSubmitted

    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&trade)
    if errs := tradeValidator.Validate(trade); errs != nil {
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(errs)
        return

    }
    internal := InternalTrade{
        Id: strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(1000000)),
        Trade: &trade,
    }


    tradeSubmitted.ClientTradeId = trade.ClientTradeId
    tradeSubmitted.TradeId = internal.Id

    trades = append(trades, internal)

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&tradeSubmitted)

}
```

Comment: See https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter it's all there in the docs

Comment: The docs give the func to catch an error but not how to customize messages and return the message to response, unless I am missing it in the docs?

Comment: @dmc94: `WriteHeader(statusCode int)` - and it is in the  documentation for `Responsewriter` which Vorspring has explicitly linked to. The whole interface has only three methods so how hard did you look at the linked documentation?

Comment: @dmc94: *"add a custom error message" - the status message in HTTP has no real meaning, the whole meaning comes from the status code.

Comment: You may use the [`http.Error()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error) function to send back an HTTP status code with error message. If you want a "more custom" error response (such as a JSON error message), set proper content type, then use `ResponseWriter.WriteHeader()` and assemble your custom response body manually.

Comment: See [Terminating or aborting an HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293314/terminating-or-aborting-an-http-request/31293435#31293435) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO Request validation should always return 400.

422 is design for different purpose - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2

> 11.2.  422 Unprocessable Entity
>
> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

If your request does not pass validation that means its syntax is not correct.

After your validation is successfully finished, you can have additional checks and there you can return 422.

But look at this issue from different perspective.

Is it really so important to distinguish between 400 and 422? Is that realistic that client side software (not human) will take any advantage from it?

I am focusing on software here because people can read message and codes are redundant for us.

Let me give you an example for proper software reaction to status code.

Reliable systems should support different error codes and distinguish cases where retry can help deliver message vs cases where retry is useless because it always fails (unless we change server code). By returning 400, we are giving a hint to the client telling that retry will not help. Client can implement branch in code and retry request for 500 and finish execution for 400.

Does additional 422 code add any value?

Comment: This is all good information, and I agree with it completely, but it doesn't answer the question.